# Esc/pos convert hex to decimal for Set absolute horizontal print position

Tags: vb.net, escpos

I need to print a ticket, the project is designed in vb.net, but I can not make a horizontal position, according to [Epson documentation](http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/36/w3m-ESCPOS_Guide.pdf) is done as follows:

```
PRINT # 1, CHR $ (& H1B), "$"; CHR $ (28); CHR $ (2); "114.00"; CHR $ (& HA);
```

however I dont know how change the commands as CHR $ (& H1B) to decimal, like this that I use:

```
Public Const txtCentre As String = Chr (27) + Chr (97) + "1"

Public Const txtLeft As String = Chr (27) + Chr (97) + "0"

Public Const txtRight As String = Chr (27) + Chr (97) + "2"
```

I also read about the command ESC $ nL nH but do not understand how to write, I write so

`Public Const txtCol1 As String = Chr (27) + Chr (36) + "15" + "0"` but does not work

Please if someone can help me I will be very grateful!

Comment: Why do you need to change the commands? Is't those commands interpreted by the printer? Btw, the snippet from the documentation is not correct. You've introduced multiple space characters. Here's how it should be: `PRINT #1, CHR$(&H1B);"$";CHR$(28);CHR$(2);"114.00";CHR$(&HA);`

Comment: no, is not, vb.net can't send those commands, It is frustrating because I tried to many ways and don`t print and nothing happends :(